# Creating a one-to-many relationship with a pre-existing database with records

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a one-to-many relationship between the YahooTickerSymbol and PriceHistory database. However, I already have some data in the PriceHistory database without any keys relating to the YahooTickerSymbol database. Is there a way to create the relationship without violating the foreign key constraint?

```
class YahooTickerSymbols(models.Model):
    yahoo_ticker_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, )
    yahoo_ticker_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=20, )
    yahoo_company_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['yahoo_company_name', ]
        verbose_name_plural = "Yahoo Ticker Symbols"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s is %s." % (self.yahoo_company_name, self.yahoo_ticker_symbol)

class PriceHistory(models.Model):
    price_data_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, )
    yahoo_ticker_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=20, )
    price_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, )
    price_open = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=3, )
    price_high = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=3, )
    price_low = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=3, )
    price_close = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=3, )
    price_adjusted_close = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=3, )
    price_volume = models.BigIntegerField()
    yahootickersymbol = models.ForeignKey(YahooTickerSymbols, blank=True, null=True,
                                          on_delete=models.SET_NULL, )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['yahoo_ticker_symbol', 'price_date', ]
        verbose_name_plural = "Historical Prices"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s : %s" % (self.yahoo_ticker_symbol, self.price_date, self.price_close)
```

The code in the migration file is as follows:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('investments', '0009_auto_20160124_1517'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='pricehistory',
            name='yahootickersymbol',
            field=models.ForeignKey(to='investments.YahooTickerSymbols', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you'll be breaking any foreign key constraints since yahooticketsymbol already has `null=True`. If a `PriceHistory` doesn't have a `YahooTicketSymbol`, it will be set to `null`. Are you running into issues when you're migrating the database?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Django keeps throwing up errors when I try running the "migrate" command.

Comment: Could you post the source of the migration for adding the foreign key?

Comment: I have posted the latest migration file as an edit in my question. Hopefully, this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I made a mistake in the process of running the `makemigrations` command.

Previously, I did not set `null=True` for `models.ForeignKey` and I ran the `makemigrations` command. After realizing my error, I included `null=True` within `models.py`. However, I did not delete the previous migration files. As such, Django was stuck in trying to run the old migration files even though these were not possible to be effected.

To resolve this, you need to run `showmigrations` to understand which migration files have not been included to understand the root of the problem.